# Postgresql with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to migrate from sqlite3 to postgresql. After doing search I found that I should change my database.yml to somthing like that:

```html
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: [insert your dev database name]
  pool: 5
  username: [insert your user name]
  password:
```

But I don't know what to provide in place of database, username and password. Because i don't remember creating any of them. I just created my rails app and migrations , and thats it.

Comment: Have you tried going to the postgres cli `psql` and type `\du` to show your roles? Then perform `rake db:create`?

Answer (score 2):

To configure your rails project with postgres database
do the below steps.
provide your database details in the `database.yml` file
eg:

```
development:
  username: postgres
  database: ur-db-dev
  password: pass
  encoding: UTF8
  adapter:  postgresql
  timeout:  500
  pool:     5
```

add postgres gem in your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'pg'
```

then,

1. Do `bundle install` to install postgres gem
2. `rake db:create` to create your database
3. `rake db:migrate` to migrate your migration files

Comment: get an error "Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>... etc} The question is where do i get that database name,username with password. Because it says that my password is wrong for user.

Comment: in psql you create a database and use it here or create a fresh database by your rails command `rake db:create`. Database user name, password is you configured when you installed your postgres.  use this command and login into postgres to create new user with password `psql  -U postgres`. For more info about psql user http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-add-postgresql-user-account/